# Storing and unpacking a very long array of ints in C

Tags: c, serialization, deserialization

I have a very long array of ints (3,000,000+) that I want to store and be able to unpack quickly. At first, I wrote each int on a separate line in a text file, but that took rather long to unpack as the strings had to be converted back to ints. Then, someone suggested that I just write the array itself to the file, but when I read it back and print out the elements, it only prints zeroes. The code looked something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 3000000

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    int *arr = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(int));

    /* initialization of arr not shown */

    fwrite(arr, sizeof(int), LENGTH, f);
    fclose(f);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

And then to unpack the data:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 3000000

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    int *arr = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(int));
    fread(arr, sizeof(int), LENGTH, f);
    fclose(f);

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

But, as I said, it only prints zeroes. Why does this not work, and is there a more appropriate way of doing such a thing?

Comment: Check the return value of `fread` and `fwrite` to make sure you read / wrote the number of items you expected.  Also, start by testing with a smaller array size.

Comment: Instead of *assuming* how big the file is, why not use `ftell` and find out?

Comment: If your question is *"What would be the best way..."*, then answer wil be opinion based and question should be closed. If your question is *"Why does this not work?"* then you need have better error handling to figure out where the problem is. Either way this question cannot be answered with information you have given. Please [edit] your question to make it answerable.

Comment: Problem is not sufficiently presented in code.  Please post enough code that demos the problem (after applying this recommended [improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66458409/storing-and-unpacking-a-very-long-array-of-ints-in-c#comment117488946_66458409))

Comment: "initialization of arr not shown" may  be not performing as expected.

Comment: The initialization was not the problem. After including the "b" in the file access mode, everything works.

Comment: @tadman So `ftell` returns the size of the file in bytes? Would the length of the array then be `ftell(f) / sizeof(int)`?

Comment: It's an old trick where you `fseek` to the end of the file, `ftell` to get the offset, then seek  back to the beginning and read that number of bytes. Presuming your data is all `int` then your math checks out. Keep in mind in the real world sometimes files are actively being appended to while you read them, or they can get truncated when you're in the middle of reading.

Comment: How about using mmap to map the entire file to memory? You wouldn't even need to have the entire 3 million elements allocated at the same time and leave it up to the system to cache whatever it deems necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

1. When reading and writing the `int`s directly, you must open the file with the mode `b` as well:

   ```
    // Open for writing
    FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.bin", "wb");


    // Open for reading:
    FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.bin", "rb");
   ```
2. When calling `malloc` you should *always* check that the return value is not `NULL` to ensure that the allocation succeeded. When allocating `3000000 * sizeof(int)` bytes, not checking for success is a disaster waiting to happen. You should also check the return values of `fopen`, `fread`, and `fwrite`:

   ```
    // Checking malloc for success
    arr = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(int));
    if(NULL == arr)
    {
         perror("malloc");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Checking fopen for success:
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
    if(NULL == fp)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Checking fread for success:
    size_t readCnt = fread(arr, sizeof(int), LENGTH, fp); 
    if(readCnt != LENGTH)
    {
        // Did not read file successfully
    }

    // Checking fwrite for success:
    size_t writtenCnt = fwrite(arr, sizeof(int), LENGTH, fp);
    if(writtenCnt != LENGTH)
    {
        // Did not write file successfully
    }
   ```